# Wrong job displayed in my Developer Story headline

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, developer-story

I started a new role this month, so the other day I marked my prior role as ending in October 2016, and added my new one beginning in October 2016. I then swapped over the "Current position" indicator.

On the Developer Story timeline, these roles are rendered correctly. In the heading banner, they are not: my prior role is displayed under my name.

So, that's a bug. :)

*(My DS is currently marked private, so I guess only devs can see it…)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title in the personal info section is not dynamically generated based on your current position.  So, this isn't a bug it's actually [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

At this time, I'm not sure if there are plans to make it dynamically populate with your current position.

Comment: Oh, I see, I have to edit it manually. I didn't realise that because I have never set it manually - it was originally automatically populated with what was, at the time, my current role. It might be worth making that clearer!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit did you import from Careers? If so and the other position was your current job, the import logic tried to guess your title based on the current job.

Comment: Maybe. I don't remember. I don't particularly recall doing anything. It all just sort of... appeared...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok if you didn't hit the re-import from Careers it was loaded when we moved everything over and that import guessed based on what was your current position.

Comment: This could probably be "fixed" by making it more obvious what can be edited. At the moment you can click on the paragraphs to reveal a textbox, okay, but there's no visual cue ahead of time that this is possible. At least not one that I spotted... (I would then have deduced that, as a freeform text field that can be edited by myself, the banner "role" description is likely not automatically tied to my timeline.)

Comment: Quick question for you @LightnessRacesinOrbit do you not see the "Edit" button when you hover over your personal info section, statement, and tags?

Comment: Hm, yes I do... :$

Comment: Hmm ok, I can bring up to the dev/designers that we might need a different visual cue, if you think that is not enough.

Comment: I don't really know any more :( _Maybe_ make the temporary background colour a little clearer (add dotted border?) but it would appear that I was largely being silly.

Comment: Well I'll bring it to their attention, not saying any changes would happen soon or ever, but I will bring it up with the team. :)

Comment: Cool beans feeto.